# unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP_MV error

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am trying to pull huge data from Oracle using SSIS package but the package fails after 2 hours and i am getting this error:

```
"[OLE DB Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P027
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP_MV".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P027
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP_MV".
```

I have researched this error and could not find a helpfull solution. I am not sure how to solve this issue please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing something that requires more temporary space than the `TEMP_MV` tablespace can accommodate.  Realistically, this either means that you need to reduce the amount of temporary space that your process requires (if, for example, you have inadvertently done a Cartesian join on two large tables because you are missing a join condition, you are running too many parallel slaves, etc.) or you (or the DBA) need to allocate more space to the `TEMP_MV` tablespace or you need to organize your processing so that other pieces of code that are using large amounts of space in `TEMP_MV` are not running at the same time your code is running.  If you have multiple temporary tablespaces, you may also need to change your processing to use the other, larger temporary tablespace.  Without knowing exactly what you are doing, it's hard to know which of these options is most likely.

Comment: thanks, it is only one query that i am using to pull the data and they query uses several that tables to join them togather but the data i am pulling is about 24 month of data so it could be the data i am pulling is huge

Comment: @moe - Well, you presumably know (or can find out) how big your tablespace is, roughly how much temporary space your query should need, and whether it's reasonable to run out of temp space.